# Google analytics seems to be registering their own bots as visitors, what the heck do I do?

Tags: google-analytics, bots

I blogged about it more in depth here: http://twicsy.tumblr.com/post/85910948424/google-bot-now-messing-up-google-analytics

Long story short, I see a lot of traffic (50-60,000 visits yesterday, and still coming in today) coming from "google inc." when I look in the network section of Google analytics. The traffic is very highly suspicious. I think it is a bot, but I guess there is a small chance it is some sort of proxy. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am doing a secondary dimension analysis and I found that the network domain is indeed googlebot.com.